# Как занести нажатие кнопки и ее текст в переменную для дальнейшего использования?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Нужно занести нажатие кнопки по определению пола в переменную для дальнейшего использования. Но когда пытаюсь определить callback_data кнопок в callback_query и вывести ответ для пользователя, пишет в консоли:
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id= is not handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=

Не особо понимаю как определить для диспетчера этот хендлер, то есть что нужно здесь прописывать @dp.callback_query(----), а так же как занести ответ в саму переменную.
Сами кнопки по старту вылезают.

Вот код:

```
@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    kb = [
        [
            types.KeyboardButton(text='Мужской',
                                 callback_data='male'),
            types.KeyboardButton(text='Женский',
                                 callback_data='female')
        ],
    ]

    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=kb,
        resize_keyboard=True,
        input_field_placeholder='Выбирайте...'
    )
    await message.answer('Выберите пол', reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.callback_query(cmd_start)
async def process_gender(call: CallbackQuery):
    gender = call.data
    await call.message.answer(f"Вы выбрали: {gender}")
    await call.answer()
```

Comment: Тебе нужно отлавливать callback_data. @dp.callback_query(F.data == 'male') Это для первой кнопки. Если callback_data в таком виде, как у тебя, то для второй кнопки тоже нужен хендлер

Comment: Пробовал уже так делать с фильтром F, но все равно не работает. Возможно потому что не правильно заношу значения в переменную, не знаю. И есть ли способ в одном хендлере уместить две кнопки? То есть при выборе любой из кнопок значение так же будет занесено в переменную.

Comment: Так, подожди. У тебя же обычная реплай клавиатура. У нее нет callback_data, соответственно и callback_query срабатывать не будет. При нажатии на кнопку бот получает просто текст, который написан на кнопке. Все. Соответственно, и обрабатывать его нужно как текст

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, то есть callback_data есть только у инлайн кнопок? И в обычные ее не засунуть?

Comment: Изменил хендлер на ответ к сообщению:
@dp.message(F.text.lower() == 'Мужской') 
async def process_gender(message: types.Message): 
    await message.answer("Вы выбрали мужской", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
Но почему то так же консоль выдает, что это не хендлер...

Comment: Да, только у инлайн-кнопок есть. Конечно выдает, ты же приводишь текст сообщения к строчным буквам и сравниваешь со словом, которое начинается с заглавной буквы - они не совпадают

Comment: Я все понял, большое спасибо за объяснение. Теперь все заработало)